# What is the number of subsets of $S$ having cardinality $k$ and containing the number $1$?

Tags: probability, statistics

Given $S = {1, 2, ..., 2n}$; what is the number of subsets of $S$ having cardinality $k$ and containing the number $1$?

The number of subsets of a set is $2^n$ but I don't know how to go on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are effectively choosing $k-1$ elements from a list of $2n-1$ so the number of subsets is given by
$$\binom{2n-1}{k-1}$$

Comment: I don't get it.

Comment: As one of the items is already chosen - $1$ - you are left with $k-1$ elements to choose for the new subset. The number of selectable items is now $2n-1$ as $1$ cannot be selected again.

Comment: If $S$ contains one number surely then we need only to take $k-1$ numbers from $2n-1$ numbers in the list to form $S.$

Comment: What is the item already chosen?

Comment: The number $1$ as I indicated in the previous comment.

Comment: So $2^n$ is not needed?

Comment: No, it's not needed at all

Comment: So for example the number of subsets with cardinality $k$ and that don't contain even number is $$\binom{2n/2}{k}$$?

Comment: Yes this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You know one of the element of your subset is 1, so there are k-1 more to choose. Do you know how many subsets of size k-1 (to be chosen among 2*n-1 elements) there are?...